# How to split the data frame by column and save to separate files as csv?

Tags: pandas, split

I have a dataframe like as follows contains (14000 columns)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10),columns=range(20))
df
```

The data frame looks like following but NaN has different values

```
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I want to split the dataframe by column to multiple dataframe and save as separate csv
1.csv

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

2.csv

```
    9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

and 3.csv

```
18  19
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For split by each N column use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by integer division per each `N` columns and write to files:

```
N = 9
for i, g in df.groupby(df.columns // N, axis=1):
    g.to_csv(f'file_{i+1}.csv', index=False)
```

Or if possible not `RangeIndex` in columns use:

```
N = 9
for i, g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // N, axis=1):
    g.to_csv(f'file_{i+1}.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `iloc` accross the columns will yield the result you wish. Example below for the first 10 columns

```
df.iloc[:, 0:10].to_csv('df1.csv')
```